# align material-ui boxs vertically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

i am making a controlls box in react with material ui and I have a component called controllers which have 4 controller components inside it the problem is, i want the button boxes aligned vertically so the length of the labels dont shift the buttons forward. and I dont want to use table just using box and here is my code. I used justifyContent, alignItems, alignContent and none is working

[image]
  any help?

here is the controllers component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Buildcontroller from "./buildcontroller";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";

export function Buildcontrols(props) {
return (
    <Box pl={5} mt={-2}>
        <h4>price: {props.totalprice} $</h4>


            {props.itemsList.map((p =>

             //itemsList is an array holding 4 names 

                    <Buildcontroller itemCount={props.itemsObject[p]} label={p} less={() => {
                        props.less(p)
                    }} more={() => {
                        props.more(p)
                    }}/>
            ))}

    </Box>
);
};
```

and here is the controller component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";

export default function Buildcontroller(props) {

return (
    <Box display="flex" mb={1}>
            <Box mr={4} mt={0.5} row={1}>
                {/*row=1*/}

                    {props.label}
            </Box>
        <Box flexShrink={1}
             justifyContent="flex-end"
             alignItems="flex-end"
             alignContent="flex-end"
        >
            <Button variant={"contained"} color={"secondary"} disabled={(props.itemCount === 0)}
                    onClick={props.less}>less</Button>
            <Button variant={"contained"} color={"primary"} onClick={props.more}>more</Button>
        </Box>

    </Box>

);
};
```

Comment: You should set fixed width for labels like width: 50px

Comment: thanks bro it worked!

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle with plain CSS to show how you can achieve this without setting fixed widths on the labels (which I personally wouldn't recommend) https://jsfiddle.net/tq07mad6/